# How to use custom CSS file with swagger-ui-express in Node JS

Tags: css, swagger-ui, swagger-ui-express

In our **index.js** file:

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
...
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, { customCssUrl: '/docs.css' }));
```

In the same top-level directory as our **index.js** file is our **docs.css** file

```
h2 {
    color: darkred;
}
```

And the error we are getting:
[image]

CBB Analytics API is an `h2` element, clearly not `darkred`, clearly the doc is not applying the styles because of the error message in the console. How can we troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution pretty quick to this.

```
// serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use('*.css', (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    next();
});
```

Needed to make sure that the server was sending the correct MIME type for the CSS file. In this case, we needed to set the MIME type to "text/css" for the "docs.css" file.